# Translate Excel/VBA to Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

I found an Excel/VBA script here and am trying to translate it to Python. First is the VBA, then my Python attempt. How should I fix the Python code?

```
Public Function GetUPSDeliveryDate(ByVal id As String) As String
Dim body As String, json As Object
body = "{""Locale"":""en_US"",""TrackingNumber"":[""" & id & """]}"
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "POST", "https://www.ups.com/track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US", False
    .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&requester=ST/"
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
    .setRequestHeader "DNT", "1"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    .send body
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With
```

[Excel VBA/JSON to scrape UPS tracking delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897092/excel-vba-json-to-scrape-ups-tracking-delivery)

My attempt is:

```
def f(tn):
  data = {"Locale":"en_US",
    "TrackingNumber":f"[{tn}]",
    "Referer": "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&requester=ST/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"}

  r = requests.post("https://www.ups.com/track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US", data=data)
  print(r.json())
```

My guess is one problem is putting the `body` portion from VBA into `data`.

Comment: As @Tim Roberts' answer says, right now you are including all the headers in the POST data. They should be passed in separately as headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right.  Locale and TrackingNumber are part of the data.  Everything else is a request header.

```
def f(tn):
  data = {"Locale":"en_US",
    "TrackingNumber":f"[{tn}]"}
  headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&requester=ST/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"}

  r = requests.post("https://www.ups.com/track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US", data=data, headers=headers)
  print(r.json())
```

Comment: Thanks.  Alas, I'm getting an Access Denied error, but that would seem a problem with the original code (which I have not tested).